# MissingMethodException on ToParametrizedSql method when use EFCore7

Tags: ef-core-7.0, efcore.bulkextensions

We upgraded our project from EF6 to EF7 (.Net6 solution) and after that on ToParametrizedSql method we started to get

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalCommand Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QuerySqlGenerator.GetCommand(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SelectExpression)'.

at EFCore.BulkExtensions.IQueryableExtensions.ToParametrizedSql(IQueryable query)
```

Is there any substitute or Nugget package to be able to use this method?